# Showing and Hiding Widget give SetState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error

Tags: flutter

I have some trouble with hiding and showing widget. So, I have an OTP verification page to verify the code that sent to the user. In that page, when a user click a text button to resend otp code, the button will be hidden and replaced by countdown timer.

```
         showCountdown ?
              Center(
                child: CountdownTimer(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  endTime: endTime,
                  onEnd: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showCountdown = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
             :
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Tidak Menerima Kode Verifikasi? ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // userService.resendOtp(widget.phoneNumber.toString()).then((value) => snackBar(value));
                      setState(() {
                        showCountdown = true;
                        clicked++;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Kirim Ulang",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Constant.color,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

First click is okay, but when clicked for second time, it give this error

```
The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

It shows that the error maybe on this part

```
 onEnd: () {
    setState(() {
      showCountdown = false;
    });
 },
```

Full Code for build method

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/Background.png"),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
              )
          ),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              // SizedBox(height: 30),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Verifikasi Nomor HP',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Kode Dikirim Ke Nomor ",
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "${widget.phoneNumber}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 15)),
                      ],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15)),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 30),
                    child: PinCodeTextField(
                      appContext: context,
                      pastedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Constant.color,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      length: 6,
                      obscureText: false,
                      obscuringCharacter: '*',
                      blinkWhenObscuring: true,
                      animationType: AnimationType.fade,
                      validator: (v) {
                        if (v!.length < 6) {
                          return "Harap Masukan Kode OTP Yang Benar";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      pinTheme: PinTheme(
                        shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        fieldHeight: 50,
                        fieldWidth: 40,
                        activeFillColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      errorAnimationController: errorController,
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      boxShadows: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                      onCompleted: (v) {
                        print("Completed");
                      },
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        print(value);
                        setState(() {
                          currentText = value;
                        });
                      },
                      enablePinAutofill: true,
                      beforeTextPaste: (text) {
                        print("Allowing to paste $text");
                        //if you return true then it will show the paste confirmation dialog. Otherwise if false, then nothing will happen.
                        //but you can show anything you want here, like your pop up saying wrong paste format or etc
                        return true;
                      },
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                child: Text(
                  hasError ? "*Please fill up all the cells properly" : "",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              showCountdown ?
              Center(
                child: CountdownTimer(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  endTime: endTime,
                  onEnd: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showCountdown = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
             :
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Tidak Menerima Kode Verifikasi? ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // userService.resendOtp(widget.phoneNumber.toString()).then((value) => snackBar(value));
                      setState(() {
                        showCountdown = true;
                        clicked++;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Kirim Ulang",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Constant.color,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 14,
              ),
              Container(
                margin:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 30),
                child: ButtonTheme(
                  height: 50,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      formKey.currentState!.validate();
                      // conditions for validating
                      if (currentText.length != 6 ) {
                        errorController!.add(ErrorAnimationType.shake); // Triggering error shake animation
                        setState(() => hasError = true);
                      } else {
                        userService.verifyOtp(widget.phoneNumber.toString(), currentText).then((value) {
                          if(value == "Kode OTP Salah") {
                            errorController!.add(ErrorAnimationType.shake);
                            textEditingController.clear();
                            setState(() {
                              hasError = true;
                              snackBar(value);
                            });
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              hasError = false;
                              snackBar(value);
                            });
                            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then( (value) =>
                                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SignIn()))
                            );
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Verifikasi Kode OTP".toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Constant.color,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.green.shade200,
                          offset: Offset(1, -2),
                          blurRadius: 5),
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.green.shade200,
                          offset: Offset(-1, 2),
                          blurRadius: 5)
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I dont have any idea why this is happened, so I need help for this. Thank you.

Comment: There is no problem in the code you added. Can you add full code?

Comment: @SalihCan Sure, but its a bit long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the Flutter Engine is instructed to build something (using `setState` for example), but at the very moment another build is already in progress.

So you have to find out which of your `setState` statements causes this error,  it could be the one at `onEnd`, you can debug your code to be sure. Than you can add a callback, which will be executed after the current build is completed:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    setState(() {
      
    });
});
```

If you haven't already done, include this in your `main` function:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp()); // or whatever you app class name is
}
```

Comment: Hello, I already put `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`. Looks like the main problem is `CountdownTimer` widget, because when I change that to a `Text`, its works fine. Still dont have any solutions thought

Comment: Have you tried to wrap `setState` into the callback? The one in `onEnd` of `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: Thank you, looks like I wrap the wrong statements, its working now.